# Facebook API Picture gives me a wrong image?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I've got an issue and I can't figure out what I did wrong.
On a server side kotlin code, I use Facebook login to retrieve a user information. For instance, me !
This works fine, I've got something like:

> [#FacebookProfile# | id: 10159838014524687 | attributes: {birthday=Fri Nov 19 00:00:00 CET 1982, access_token=EAAIDdkm8AzIBABDZATUZBhGMGWHKAwUACsLqMS2

Then, I take this Id to use Facebook api to retrieve the user picture:
https://graph.facebook.com/10159838014524687/picture

Ok, sounds great, but I only have a "generic" picture:
[Generic picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM7ob.png)

However, I really have a profile picture in my Facebook account !
This is me !! => [Facebook picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCUHH.png)

Is it normal that the picture is not displayed ? Thanks a lot for the help !!

Comment: You need to pass the access token with the API call the gets the profile picture, this is explicitly explained under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Answer (score 0):

Actually there were no issue except than the ID I was using was maybe wrong (can't remember why).
But there is also a hint: instead of using the ID, use "me":
https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture